# find the min and max values of nested list by index of element in nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list like the following:

```
x = [[1,  5, 3,  4], 
     [5, 10, 7,  8], 
     [9,  9, 2, 12]]
```

I need to find to find the min and max values of the nested list **transposed** such that the result for min is:

```
1, 5, 2, 4  # 1 is the min of first column (1, 5, 9) a.s.o
```

and the max should be:

```
9, 10, 7, 12
```

I tried to convert it into a `dataframe` first and then doing max and min on the different axis but all doesn't come up as the result I want.

Comment: where did the `4` come from on the `min`? and same for the `9` and `7` for `max`? Why do you have 4 values in the results when the nested lists are just 3?

Comment: `z = [min(i) for i in x]` gives the list with all the minimums , and `z = [max(i) fro i in x]` would give otherwise!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following using the built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min), [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) functions and the `zip(*...)` transpositioning pattern:

```
min_x = list(map(min, zip(*x)))
max_x = list(map(max, zip(*x)))
```

Or as pointed out by [Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands), this shortened form will also work:

```
min_x = list(map(min, *x))
max_x = list(map(max, *x))
```

Or use comprehensions:

```
min_x = [min(col) for col in zip(*x)]
max_x = [max(col) for col in zip(*x)]
```

If you desperately want to do it one line:

```
min_x, max_x = zip(*[(min(col), max(col)) for col in zip(*x)])
```

Comment: `list(map(min, *x))`

Comment: 90% of the time, the hardest part about a question is understanding it; not the actual coding difficulties.. Good work! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension or other way:

```
print([min(item) for item in zip(*x)])
```

is same as:

```
min_list=[]
for i in zip(*x):
    min_list.append(min(i))
print(min_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 5, 2, 4]
```

For max:

```
print([max(item) for item in zip(*x)])
```

is same as:

```
max_list=[]
for i in zip(*x):
    max_list.append(max(i))

print(max_list)
```

output:

```
[9, 10, 7, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply with **`numpy`** module:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,  5, 3,  4], [5, 10, 7,  8], [9,  9, 2, 12]])
print(np.min(x, 0))    # [1 5 2 4]
print(np.max(x, 0))    # [ 9 10  7 12]
```